# unlink y file_put_contents permission denied

Tags: php, linux, apache

Estoy tratando de realizar un unlink y un file_put_contents y no me permite realizar la operación con todo y las variables de Linux correctas (el usuario correcto, permisos en 777 por si las dudas), ya había posteado varias pruebas y formas para buscar la solución, y en esta edición trataré de ponerlo más resumido con una prueba principal mostrando el código y la prueba.

Los datos principales de software del servidor son: Apache 2.4, PHP 5.4 y CentOS 7.5, usuario del apache es "apache" y el de los archivos y directorio contenedor es "apache".

No es una pregunta fácil no es la primera vez que borro un archivo por medio de PHP, la pregunta es y sigue siendo **¿Cómo borro el archivo por medio del servicio web? ¿Cómo uso el file_put_contents en el servicio web? ¿Qué configuración me falta?** Esto me sucedió al migrar mis aplicaciones de servidor y probé este ejemplo sencillo del error.

**Adjunto imagen con la prueba con permisos 777**

[image: Prueba con permisos 777]

Comment: Acabo de agregar un echo exec('whoami'); y la respuesta fue apache, en el cmd lo ejecute con root, no puedo ejecutarlo con usuario apache pero sigo buscándole

Comment: ¿? ¿Cómo queda la pregunta? La respuesta es que normalmente apache se ejecuta con su propio usuario y que los permisos que importan son los del usuario apache, pero parece que ya has llegado a esa conclusión.

Comment: Es que si te fijas los archivos del directorio `dirt1` solo tienen permisos de lectura y escritura. Como parece que el propietario es apache, prueba a cambiar los permisos antes del `unlink()` con `chmod($lstrFileDelete, 0777);`

Comment: "aún poniendo el mod en 777 del directorio y de los archivos me sigue sin funcionar"

Comment: La pregunta es, ¿como le hago para borrar el archivo? ya revise todos los permisos de linux, el usuario del apache puse el chmod 777, no sé que me esta faltando...

Comment: en esta pregunta de unix stackexchange dice que se necesita tener permiso de ejecucion en todos los directorios padres al que quieres borrar, ademas de permisos de escritura en el direcotrio padre directo.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137601/minimum-file-permissions-to-delete-a-file

Comment: No creo que eso sea nada seguro, poner permisos 777 a todos los directorios padre hasta llegar ¿hasta donde? ¿al de "/" (raíz)?, de una vez abro la puerta del DataCenter. El directorio padre tiene permisos y es del usuario apache además ya dije ya intente poner permisos 777 al directorio y al archivo, voy a adjuntar imagen que lo comprueba.

Comment: Ya realice varias pruebas más y puse la imagen prometida

Comment: fijate si no estas teniendo problemsa con SELinux `sestatus` te dice si está corriendo, tal vez tengas que tocar un poco la configuración para que el apache pueda borrar cosas

Comment: Jojo gracias alo Malbarez, ya lo solucionamos y si, efectivamente el problema era SELinux

Comment: Gracias por haber revisado la pregunta y haberse tomado el tiempo para estudiarla, si me ayudan con un punto arriba a la pregunta se los agradeceré

Answer (score 1):

Después de una investigación de uno de mis muchachos de desarrollo, encontró que el problema fue por que al migrar las aplicaciones a un nuevo servidor Linux CentOS 7.5, se instaló por default valores en el SELinux que no permitían la ejecución de funciones de PHP a través de Apache para el manejo de archivos. Nunca me había encontrado con problemas con SELinux (Security Enhanced Linux) ni sabía que existía, la liga en inglés es: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux

Para editar los valores del SELinux tuvimos que instalar un manejador de las herramientas SELinux con:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install policycoreutils-python
```

Después ejecutar un comando para visualizar que políticas de seguridad se encontraban activadas con el comando:

```
[root@localhost ~]# semanage boolean -l | grep httpd
```

Y empezar a abrir puertas a diferentes permisos con:

```
[root@localhost ~]# setsebool -P httpd_permiso_a_activar 1
```

Al final de mover las banderas tomando de referencia otros servidores Linux donde tenemos una arquitectura parecida, nos quedo una configuración como esta:

```
[root@localhost ~]# semanage boolean -l | grep httpd
httpd_can_network_relay        (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can network relay
httpd_can_connect_mythtv       (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can connect mythtv
httpd_can_network_connect_db   (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can network connect db
httpd_use_gpg                  (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to use gpg
httpd_dbus_sssd                (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to dbus sssd
httpd_enable_cgi               (on   ,   on)  Allow httpd to enable cgi
httpd_verify_dns               (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to verify dns
httpd_dontaudit_search_dirs    (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to dontaudit search dirs
httpd_use_cifs                 (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to use cifs
httpd_manage_ipa               (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to manage ipa
httpd_run_stickshift           (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to run stickshift
httpd_enable_homedirs          (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to enable homedirs
httpd_dbus_avahi               (on   ,   on)  Allow httpd to dbus avahi
httpd_unified                  (on   ,   on)  Allow httpd to unified
httpd_mod_auth_pam             (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to mod auth pam
httpd_can_network_connect      (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can network connect
httpd_execmem                  (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to execmem
httpd_use_fusefs               (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to use fusefs
httpd_mod_auth_ntlm_winbind    (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to mod auth ntlm winbind
httpd_use_sasl                 (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to use sasl
httpd_tty_comm                 (on   ,   on)  Allow httpd to tty comm
httpd_sys_script_anon_write    (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to sys script anon write
httpd_graceful_shutdown        (on   ,   on)  Allow httpd to graceful shutdown
httpd_can_connect_ftp          (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can connect ftp
httpd_run_ipa                  (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to run ipa
httpd_read_user_content        (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to read user content
httpd_use_nfs                  (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to use nfs
httpd_can_connect_zabbix       (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can connect zabbix
httpd_tmp_exec                 (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to tmp exec
httpd_run_preupgrade           (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to run preupgrade
httpd_can_sendmail             (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can sendmail
httpd_builtin_scripting        (on   ,   on)  Allow httpd to builtin scripting
httpd_can_connect_ldap         (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can connect ldap
httpd_can_check_spam           (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can check spam
httpd_can_network_memcache     (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can network memcache
httpd_can_network_connect_cobbler (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can network connect cobbler
httpd_anon_write               (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to anon write
httpd_serve_cobbler_files      (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to serve cobbler files
httpd_ssi_exec                 (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to ssi exec
httpd_use_openstack            (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to use openstack
httpd_enable_ftp_server        (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to enable ftp server
httpd_setrlimit                (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to setrlimit
```

Y así se solucionó el problema, espero que a nadie le pase, y si sí, aquí esta la solución y espero a alguien le sirva